# Using rxjs via ES6 imports

Tags: rxjs, es6-modules

This is probably more a general question around imports but I am targetting this one at rxjs.

The instructions say to import like this:

```
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

range(1, 200)
  .pipe(filter(x => x % 2 === 1), map(x => x + x))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Source: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs

Now I have rxjs downloaded into my node_modules folder, but what I don't get is that I haven't added any `<script>` tags, so how does it know where `rxjs` is? Am I supposed to be adding `<script>` tags and that is just implied knowledge?...if so, how do I know which scripts to link to?

I am targetting the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: You may want to use some module bundler, like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). It will bundle all dependencies together so you can include them with `<script>` tag

Comment: The instructions in the link imply I can do this without bundling...is that not the case?

Answer (score 1):

in your html:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

in you scripts

```js
const { Observable, Subject } = rxjs;
```

Answer (score 0):

The CDN means you have to add it as a script tag before your other code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

range(1, 200)
  .pipe(filter(x => x % 2 === 1), map(x => x + x))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
</script>
```